# Python - Way to distinguish between item index in a list and item's contents in a FOR loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, duplicates

For instance, if I wanted to cycle through a list and perform some operation on all but the final list entry, I could do this:

```
z = [1,2,3,4,2]
for item in z:
    if item != z[-1]:        
        print z.index(item)
```

But instead of getting the output "...0 1 2 3," I'd get
"...0 2 3."

Is there a way to perform an operation on all but the last item in a list (when there are IDENTICAL items in the list) without using a "for x in range (len(list) - 1)" sort of solution? I.e., I want to keep using "for item in list."

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use:

```
for index, item in enumerate(z):
    if index != len(z)-1:
        print index
```

Comment: or combine it with slicing as proposed in other answers: if you use `enumarate(z[:-1])` instead of `enumerate(z)` you can get rid of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 10):

Use a slice:

```
for item in z[:-1]:
    # do something
```

Comment: You can reduce the loop overhead of creating a slice by using the `islice` method in the itertools module like this:  `for item in itertools.islice(z, 0, len(z)-1):`

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, item in enumerate(your_list):
    do_something
```

Answer (score 1):

`[z.foo() for z in z[:-1]`

Comment: WOW--you guys are fast. Thanks so much (to all of you)!

Answer (score 0):

```
def all_but_last(iterable):
    iterable= iter(iterable)

    try: previous= iterable.next()
    except StopIteration: return

    for item in iterable:
        yield previous
        previous= item
```

Put it in a module and use it wherever you need it.

In your case, you'd do:

```
for item in all_but_last(z):
```